# Setting up a Backbone, Marionette and Epoxy Application

Tags: javascript, web, backbone.js, marionette

I am getting started using Backbone.Marionette and Epoxy. I worked with Backbone.Marionette and it works fine with no problems. However, when I tried to integrate it with Epoxy, I run some of the tutorials in the Epoxy web page (http://epoxyjs.org/tutorials.html) but they didn't work. Do I need to install anything? I imported Epoxy this way, but maybe it's not enough:

```html
<script src="scripts/lib/backbone.epoxy.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems jQuery is missing.

You need to import the scripts in this order:

- jquery
- underscore
- backbone
- backbone.epoxy
- everything else, like Marionette.